# Pulling Name Out of Schema in Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to make a function that will pull the name of the column out of a dataframe schema. So what I have is the initial function defined:

```
  val df = sqlContext.parquetFile(inputVal.toString)
  val dfSchema = df.schema
def schemaMatchP(schema: StructType) : Map[String,List[Int]] =
      schema
        // get the 1st word (column type) in upper cases
        .map(columnDescr => columnDescr
```

If I do something like this:

```
.map(columnDescr => columnDescr.toString.split(',')(0).toUpperCase)
```

I will get STRUCTFIELD(HH_CUST_GRP_MBRP_ID,BINARYTYPE,TRUE)

How do you handle a StructField so I can grab the 1st element out of each column for the schema. So my Column names: HH_CUST_GRP_MBRP_ID, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt look what the source does itself. [DataFrame.toString](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/74d8d3d928cc9a7386b68588ac89ae042847d146/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.scala#L242) has the answer :). `StructField` is a case class with a `name` property. So, just do:

```
schema.map(f => s"${f.name}")
```